# Kamailio 4.3.1 Register/200 OK asycnhornous

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, routes, sip, kamailio

I am new to Kamailio 4.3.1  and I am trying to use it as described on this http://kb.asipto.com/kamailio:k43-async-sip-routing-nodejs page. Apparently it is a new approach to make asynchronous routing using NodeJS.
I've modified a little bit the example and adapted it with a REGISTER sip and it works quite good. But now I am looking for a way to make the things a little bit more complex.
In the example the NodeJS routine is called only when the REGISTER method has been received. I am trying to make a similar asynchronous call to NodeJS when the '200 OK' comes back from the REGISTERS's destination.

If we have:

Alice---REGISTER(Alice)---> Kamailio (async call to NodeJs)---REGISTER(Alice)-->Asterisk

Later when Asterisk accepts the REGISTER the I want to have this:

Alice<---200 OK---Kamailio(async call to NodeJS)<---200 OK---Asterisk

To catch the 200 OK, I configured Kamailio to execute an async call using EVAPI, like this:

```
request_route 
{
    ....
    route(REGISTRAR);
    ....
exit;
}

route[REGISTRAR]
{
    ...
    t_on_reply("2OO_OK_RSP"); # Here I tell that I want to catch the "200 OK"
    ...
exit;
}

# When the 200 OK arrives, this code is called
onreply_route[2OO_OK_RSP]
{
    # Here is my async call to NodeJS
    evapi_async_relay("send message to NodeJS about 200 OK");
}

#When NodeJS returns
event_route[evapi:message-received] 
{
    if(200 OK)
    {
        t_countinue("..", "...", RSP_200OK)
    }
}

route[RSP_200OK]
{
    t_on_branch("MANAGE_BRANCH");
    t_on_failure("MANAGE_FAILURE");

    route(RELAY); # I am trying here to relay the 200 OK, which finishes by calling t_relay();

    exit;
}
```

So this is my configuration which is treating the 200 OK. I would like to say that it works (because at the end the 200 Ok is relayed to Alice) BUT Kamailio logs this message:
*tm [tm.c:1479]: _w_t_relay_to(): ERROR: w_t_relay_to: unsupported route  type: 4*

and I don't like this. I know that there is something wrong and when I am looking at the source code of Kamailio it is clear that this is not the right place to treat messages like "200 OK".

My question is, is there any other way (a good way) to relay/route the 200 OK, once the NodeJS has replied?  I tried also with

```
t_reply("200","OK"); instead of t_relay();
```

But this generates a SIP message "200 OK" which does not contain everything that the messages received by Asterisk. Probably I can tell Kamailio to reply by exactly the same 200 OK, that it has just received?
Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Anton

Answer (score 0):

So finally I could find how to resolve partially my problem.
I discovered that the module EVAPI proposes a method called evapi_relay() which does not suspend the current transaction but sends a messages to the NodeJS application and relays the SIP messages immediately.
I says that this resolves my problem partially because however I am still not able to make the whole procedure with suspending the transaction (without the Kamailio error). 
In my case, it is not so important, but I imagine that in some cases the problem will persist.

Anton

Answer (score -1):

[From EVAPI module documentation](http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/4.2.x/modules/evapi.html#evapi.f.evapi_async_relay): After evapi_async_relay() returns true, no relaying should happen in request_route(), it should be followed by exit.

> Relay the event data given as parameter to connected applications. Before evaluating the parameter, the request processing is suspended using tm module (using the `t_suspend()`/`t_continue()` framework). The routing of the SIP request can be continued once `event_route[evapi:message-received]` is triggered. After `evapi_async_relay()` returns true, no relaying should happen in `request_route()`, it should be followed by exit;.